# Why doesn't Java allow omitting formal parameter names in a function declaration?

Tags: java, methods, arguments, declaration

I'm looking to understand ***why*** Java designers chose to implement function declarations this way. I've often heard it said that the designers of Java wanted to avoid poor design choices made in other languages (e.g., C++) -- *multiple inheritance via classes* and *operator overloading* come to mind -- in order to keep the object-oriented model as simple as possible and to encourage good programming practices. Is that true in this case? Is this feature too expensive to implement *vis-a-vis* the (admittedly marginal) gains it provides?

The thing is, I can't see (and I'm still learning, so that probably means squat! :D) a significant implementation overhead in allowing the omission of formal parameter names in function declarations. And I can think of at least one example where this feature couldn't hurt: defining abstract functions.

Anyway, glad to hear some thoughts from people on SO. BTW, [the relevant section (8.4.1)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1) of the Java Language Specification explains *what* but doesn't talk about *why*.

EDIT: **Adding a code snippet:**

```
abstract void someFunc(int, int, int);
```

(I'm using an abstract function as this is one simple case I can think of where this feature would be handy).

Comment: The Java design tends to wait for a compelling reason to do something (and then think about it for a few more years ;)  A *why not* argument is not enough to include something.  There are generally other ways of doing the same thing (if not as elegent) such as using overloading instead, which makes the case less than compelling.

Comment: **Especially** for an `abstract` method I'd say that the parameter names are essential. Not for the compiler of curse (in fact by defaul the `.class` file doesn't even contain method argument names), but for the developer! How would you know what each parameter does if not by its name?

Comment: @Joachim, yes I see what you're saying. IMO, it's a great explanation of why good coding practice _must_ require using formal names but it doesn't seem so convincing an explanation of why you would _not_ want to have this feature in the language _at all_. If I was writing simple, self-contained code (that I knew no one else would ever use), for example, I wouldn't mind doing without formal names. Peter's answer makes much more intuitive sense to me: there's simply not a compelling enough reason to have this feature.

Comment: two comments: First: Every added feature of a language **multiplies** the complexity (not just adds to it) because of its interaction with every other feature (just look how much corner cases generics have introduced). Unless there's a **strong** case *for* adding a feature, it should be left out.  Second: even if **no one else** ever has to modify that code, you will have to in a few weeks/months and you'll have a hard time reading it. If it's really throw-away code, then learn some Groovy and write your code in a fraction of the time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop formal arguments by using overloading e.g.

```
class Three {
  public Three() {
    this(1);
  }

  public Three(int a) {
    this(a, 2);
  }

  public Three(int a, int b) {
    this(a, b, 3);
  }

  public Three(int a, int b, int c) {  }

  // can pass any number of `int` values.
  public void method1(int... varargs) {
  }

  public void method2(int a) {
     method2(a, 2);
  }

  public void method2(int a, int b) { }
}
```

EDIT: From my comment.

> The Java design tends to wait for a compelling reason to do something (and then think about it for a few more years ;) A *why not* argument is not enough to include something. There are generally other ways of doing the same thing (if not as elegent) such as using overloading instead, which makes the case less than compelling

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yeah, I read about this on another question on SO. I was kinda hoping more for an explanation of _why_ the language is this way. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @neeraj2608, I have added my earlier comment, but basicly, there is not a compeling reason to add such a feature when it can be achieved other ways.

Comment: accepted for your comment in the post: `A why not argument is not enough to include something. There are generally other ways of doing the same thing (if not as elegent) such as using overloading instead, which makes the case less than compelling`

Answer (score 3):

Why *should* it allow this?

If a method definition had no names for its parameters, how would you actually use the parameters in your code?

In C the situation is slightly different: you have the declaration and the implementation independently of each other (at least if you do it "right"). Here, leaving the information out in one place avoids duplication.

But in Java there is no separate declaration (unless you're defining a method in an interface, in which case there's no implementation, which means no duplication again). There's *only* the implementation.

Comment: Yes, _interfaces_ and _abstract functions_ are two scenarios that I could think of where the declaration is divorced from the implementation.

Comment: @neeraj: And as I said: in those cases there is no duplication, because that point is the *only* point where you mention it. It's necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

The different answers show it is not really clear what you are asking about - putting an example in the question would have helped.

I assume you would want to be able to write

```
public void method(int a, int, int) {
}
```

instead of

```
public void method(int a, int b, int c) {
}
```

whenever `b` and `c` are not used anywhere in the method (or the method is abstract, or similar).

So, why not allow omitting them:

- It would complicate the grammar (not much, though)
- Often you would want to document the arguments, and for this you would need names for them. (This applies to interfaces and abstract/native methods, too.)
- When arguments are not used, why have them at all?
- From a theoretical viewpoint: Formal parameter declarations are a kind of variable declaration, and you can't have a variable without a name (apart from array elements).
- It could confuse readers of the code.

When I have arguments which are not used, I sometimes give them names like `ignored` or `dummy`.

Comment: Umm... Believe it or not, I actually did think about whether I should include a code snippet but I thought "omitting formal parameter NAMES in function declarations" is self-explanatory enough. :-) Anyway, it's the first one I'm talking about. I'll add a code snippet to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just part of the same philosophy that makes things strongly typed, for instance. You are expected to know what a method is and how you're using it at compile-time.

It's about having an interface that always takes the parameters you expect and returns the results you expect and throws the exceptions you expect. If we have

```
class Adder {
    int add(int a, int b) {return a+b;}
    int add(int a, int b, int c) {return a+b+c;}
    int add(int a, int b, int c, int d) {return a+b+c+d;}
}
```

Then the designers of Java are thinking: if you want to "Adder.add" two specific numbers, there's a method for that.  You would never call this method with three or four parameters, because that just makes no sense for what that method is designed to do. If you want to make "Adder.add"s three or four numbers, you should make those methods separately.

Now perhaps this is a terrible contrived example, but part of my point was to agree that this language feature doesn't always make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the **names**, not the arguments themselves, the reason is simple.  When defining abstract methods you are defining an interface.  For an interface to be usable, the person addressing it has to know the meaning of the arguments.  That's what the names are for.

Sure, your code could work just as well if you would just name your arguments *a* and *b*, but you don't.  You call them *country* or *birthplace*.  You use it to convey meaning.

Java was always meant to force programmers to do the right thing as much as possible, and to make it hard to shoot yourself in the foot.  That's why it was designed like this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a great feature, because you could get rid of that stupid annotation to ignore unused.

Let's say I had this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ListFunc {
    Stream<Path> apply( Path dir ) throws IOException;
}
void doStuff( Path dir, ListFunc listFunc ) {
    List<Path> filenames = listFunc.apply( dir ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
    ...
```

So, the simple case:

```
doStuff( Paths.get( System.getProperty( "user.home" ) ), Files::list );
```

But what about unit tests?

```
static Stream<Path> fixedListFunc( Path /* unused */ dir ) {
    List<Path> fixed = Lists.newArrayList( Paths.get( "first" ),
            Paths.get( "second" ),
            Paths.get( "third" ) );
    return fixed.stream();
}

@Test
public void testDoStuff() {
    doStuff( null, fixedListFunc );
```

Sure would be nice to be able to omit the name for the unused parameter. Instead of having to overload, or use annotations to ignore the warning in this case, or other stuff.